# Add Eclipse project as dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing my app using Android Studio, and I'd like to link to another project in Eclipse as a dependency.

The dependency project in Eclipse is ongoing as well, so I'd like to avoid importing/converting it into an Android Studio project every time there is a change to it.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: I think best option is to export your eclipse project to .jar file and add it to the AS project, and use it as library.

Comment: Ideally we'd like to avoid having to run the export/conversion every time the eclipse project updates, which should be fairly often during the development process.